# Make huge view in C# readable and maintanable

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, razor

I have an application that is using MVC5 with C# and Razor Engine.  This view displays a huge table:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="pendingTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Order Status</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Expected Delivery Date</th>
            <th>Ordered By</th>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Status</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Type</th>
            <th>Scope</th>
            <th>Delivery Address</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td> <!-- At least 8 TDs each one with hundreds of lines of code-->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, the problem is that everything is in one huge file. As you can guess, this file is a nightmare to update and maintain.

I am familiar with the C# `region` directive, but I can't find anything similar for Views. I also know about partial views, but I have the strong impression from discussions in Stack Overflow that these should only be used when I have a piece of code in a View that is re-usable, which is not the case.

What is the best way to deal with Views this large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Partial View for this code.
Anytime I have a menu for a page I put it in a partial view even though it may not be used on another page.

```
<tr>@Html.Partial("_Actions")</tr>
<tr>@Html.Partial("_OrderStatus")</tr>
<tr>@Html.Partial("_OrderDetails")</tr>
<tr>@Html.Partial("_OrderDate")</tr>
```

inside the Partial view placed in Views/Shared

```
@model ActionsViewModel
<td>Column 1</td> 
<td>Column 2</td> 
<td>Column 3</td> 
<td>Column 4</td> 
<td>Column 5</td>
```

etc...
Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Razor supports collections from model.
[Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_cs_loops.asp)
You can connect all information to the database, and maintain the data properly.

**Explanation:**
The table must be in database, **in model**, not in view.

The correct usage of MVC:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="pendingTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
         @foreach (var columnName in Model.ColumnsNames)
         {
           <th>@columnName</th>
         }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <!-- use @foreach-->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to surround the long sections with span tags. This makes the stuff inside the span collapsible in the VS editor. It's not a "solution" per se, but it can make life easier